# Efficient way to capture packets in multithreading Python program

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I'm implementing a sniffer using Python. 
I need in all packet details (VLAN etc.) so I'm using RAW sockets.
There are several sniffers working as demons on all of my Ethernet interfaces, so each one is in a different thread.

Is there any better way to get the results in my main thread besides global variable to which I add my packets (as in the code below)?

I tried Queue but didn't see any particular benefits besides added complexity.

```
import socket, threading

def ReceivePackets():
    soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.ntohs(0x0003))  
    while 1:
        packet = soc.recv(2000)  
        buffer.append(packet)

def ReadSniffer():
    result = list(buffer) 
    #Clear buffer to start sniffing from scratch after reading
    del buffer[:]
return result
```

I start sniffers on all of my Ethernet interfaces at the beginning of the program and read the corresponding global buffers when I need the data.

```
buffer = []
t = threading.Thread(target = ReceivePackets)
t.daemon = True
t.start()
...
packets = ReadSniffer()
```

Comment: The best data structure depends not only on how you collect the packets, but also how you consume them. So, how do you consume them? Also note that adding to list from multiple threads isn't thread-safe.**update:** I checked and actually they are thread-safe, however still best practice is to use queue.

Comment: 1) I construct RAW packets (ARP, DHCP, PPPoE) send them through an Ethernet L2+ switch which modifies them according to its configuration. Then I capture packets and verify that they are what I expect. I'm running class hierarchy of packets so I basically compare two RAW hex packets - one received from the interface and one constructed "virtually" in my program
2) I have several global buffers, one for each sniffer/thread. It just looks a bit ugly for me. But I verified that it works on the NIC with 4 port (so 4 sniffers) and quite decent load

Comment: Ok, how many packet consumers you have? Do they need to get the packets in some order or they just process them FIFO acting as workers?

Comment: Currently, I have a single consumer - my main thread. I know what packets I should get on each interface because I initiate the transmission with my main thread too. I try test the switch and need in multiple interface to verify that all options, including the ones replicating packets (like IGMP), work fine

Comment: Well, if you don't need distinction between packets from different interfaces, I'd go with a single Queue (even if you do, then you could just put that info with each packet in the queue). It's easier to model. Then you end up with multiple-producers single-consumer pattern.

Comment: What would be the advantage of Queue? I tried Queue and saw no particular benefits over a shared list. I need a separate buffers for each of the interfaces

Comment: In simple scenario there will be none. But as things get more complex you will be on a safer side as Queue is designed to power multi-threaded programs. You will have to be very careful when doing mutli-threaded operations on shared list.

Comment: pajton, thank you for your reply! If I don't get any more replies I'll just stick with queues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sockets I always got inconsistent results, since I have various packets with different packet size. A socket may capture all the packets I send few times, but eventually it loses some packets.

I moved to `pcapy` interface to `libcap` library instead of raw sockets and it works perfectly and very reliably.

I implemented Sniffer class as a subclass of `threading.Thread` so it starts in a separate thread. The implementation is like this:

```
class Sniffer(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, port):      
        ...
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        #Packets will be stored here
        self.result = []
        #Not worry about closing the sniffer thread
        self.daemon = True    

    #Invoked when I start my thread
    def run(self):      
        max_bytes = 16000
        #Important to capture broken packets as I need them
        promiscuous = True
        read_timeout = 100
        pc = pcapy.open_live(str(self.port), max_bytes, promiscuous, read_timeout)
        pc.loop(-1, self.recv_pkts)

    #Do when the packet arrives
    def recv_pkts(self, hdr, packet):
        packetHex = binascii.hexlify(packet)
        self.result.append(packetHex)
        return self.result
```

To start sniffer thread in parallel to your main program:

```
 sniffer1 = Sniffer(eth1)
 #Start separate thread
 sniffer1.start()
```